# CSS get parent node width....without expressions

Tags: css

I have a css class where the LEFT needs the be the WIDTH of the parent node.

The width of the parent node is unknown.

Is there a way to get the width of a parent node in CSS. (expressions are not an option).

Thanks.

```
.parent{
   display:block; 
   position:relative;
}

.child{
   position:absolute;
   left:PARENT.WIDTH;
}


<div class="parent">This is a test<span class="child">what?</span></div>
```

Hopefully that makes sense.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
.parent{
   display:block; 
   position:relative;
}

.child{
   position:absolute;
   right:-100px;
   width:100px;
}


<div class="parent">This is a test<span class="child">what?</span></div>
```

Comment: If this is the answer, both question and answer has no meaning... the Question states that the parent width is unknown, then you should access the parent node, access (somehow) the computed width, and pass it down to the children, simply put, you can't just add a number on the fly